# Chrome - Font Awesome 5 some icons are not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-awesome

I am useing Font Awesome 5. Some icons are not showing in Chrome. For example "fa-facebook-f". When I change the icon class to fa-facebook it works. Is there a way to fix it?
Here is what i see in chrome.

[image]

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-facebook">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
    </i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter">
    <i class="fab fa-twitter">
    </i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-google_plus">
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g">
    </i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-pinterest">
    <i class="fab fa-pinterest">
    </i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-linkedin">
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in">
    </i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-instagram">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram">
    </i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-tumblr">
    <i class="fab fa-tumblr">
    </i>
  </a>
```

Comment: Wait, why are you using it like that `fa fa-facebook-f` ?

Comment: which url/cdn are you using to pull the icons? Is it just the chrome that has the issue?

Comment: Make sure your site is not loading several versions of FontAwesome. I had the same issue, and resolved by it ensuring at least all includes were at the same version, waiting until it's cleaned up to have it only included once.

Answer (score 14):

Import this css it will work for all the font awesome icons and also for all the versions of icons it will work.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">`

Comment: Very good solution - https://youtu.be/tGD6xRMrtcQ

Comment: For latest version use this : 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/css/all.css">`

Answer (score 8):

Add this code in your HTML file before body and style tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And remember one thing that use class of that type

```
fab fa-linkedin
```

in some site it is given as

```
fa fa-linkedin
```

which is not working so use 'fab' in place of 'fa'

And you can use this icon in your website 
for testing purpose you can use this code

```
<div class="row text-center">
      <!-- Team item-->
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-5">
        <div class="bg-white rounded shadow-sm py-5 px-4"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mhmd/image/upload/v1556834132/avatar-4_ozhrib.png" alt="" width="100" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mb-3 img-thumbnail shadow-sm">
          <h5 class="mb-0">Vishal Jat</h5><span class="small text-uppercase text-muted">CEO - Founder</span>
          <ul class="social mb-0 list-inline mt-3">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its working fine...Its maybe you are not linking the correct font-awesome file

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-facebook">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter">
  <i class="fab fa-twitter">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-google_plus">
  <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-pinterest">
  <i class="fab fa-pinterest">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-linkedin">
  <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-instagram">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-tumblr">
  <i class="fab fa-tumblr">
    </i>
</a>
```

Comment: So why it is working in Firefox, no chrome, also why some of them are showing?

Comment: @user3351236 is the above snippet working for you...?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "fab" in class instead of "fa"

```
<i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
```

This will surely work. Replace "fa" with "fab" or "fas".

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the css, js but also the etf files which describes the font ?

If yes, then try this class name instead of "fab" which is not referenced in the doc

```
<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

This class name works fine for linkedin:

```
<i class="fab fa-linkedin-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

used the below link in index.html under head tag :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice when i add this part to the font-awesome/5.15.4/ library doesn't load.

```
integrity="sha512-Vw3RTv7vrqtzj7Umk17DszsotZa6PXj5dnTEszUbnvmVq7Jpj27GPvmXzQkMV6mPvhj1g+YY4fb7DrlLBwTVlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
```

But when i do something like this instead all the icons seem to load perfectly from the library.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-facebook">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> 
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter">
     <i class="fab fa-twitter">
    </i>
</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="icon-twitter">
     <i class="fab fa-google"></i> 
</a>
```