# Font Awesome icons not working in ASP.NET core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, font-awesome

I am trying to use the social icon of fontawesome, I have the below version.

```
 "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0"
```

I have this code

`<i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i>
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>`

in bundle config asp.net core

```
{
    "outputFileName": "ClientApp/public/vendor.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": false }
  }
```

I have tried with `fa,fas,far,fal,fad,fab` none of this works.

[image]

In the network load page I can see the css contain

```
.fa-facebook:before {
  content: "\f09a"; }

.fa-facebook-f:before {
  content: "\f39e"; }

.fa-facebook-messenger:before {
  content: "\f39f"; }

.fa-facebook-square:before {
  content: "\f082"; }
```

**It's not about the social icons only, none of the icons are working for me.**

Reference

[Chrome - Font Awesome 5 some icons are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403607/chrome-font-awesome-5-some-icons-are-not-working)

Comment: am also facing the same issue. have you somehow resolved this?

Comment: You have: "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free", i think the r in "fort" needs to be an n: "font"